# Filter messages using native apache Kafka consumers api before poll

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there an option to filter messages using native apache Kafka consumers before poll?

RecordFilterStrategy -could see option in spring, but looking for something in native apache kafka consumer api, and dont have an option to produce messages to two different topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poll` returns an iterable collection of records. There's no other way to get the records, and therefore, you cannot filter on record content beforehand (neither does Spring)

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer